# Django block not showing up

Tags: django, backend

So, originally I was using {% include}, and that was working fine, then I wanted to try out {% block}, and its not showing the nav.html content anymore. I've been trying to figure this out for about 15 minutes now, and it looks like its the same as I've seen everyone else do it. This is my code, what am i doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
It is now {{ current_date }}
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

this block of code being the current_datetime file.

```
{% extends 'current_datetime.html' %}
{% block content %} <h1>this is a test</h1> {% endblock %}
```

and this block of code being nav.html. I'm 100% sure that I'm naming the extends file correctly since I copied the name from the views file.

Comment: what is you template directories structure?

Comment: You mean the DIRS in the settings.py?
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
     'APP_DIRS': True,
Sorry, i cant get the code to look normal in a comment. It is finding all of the files correctly though, i used include nav.html earlier and it worked

Comment: Is `It is now {{ current_date }}` get rendered when you open page that renders `nav.html`?

Comment: Yep, and before that, the content in nav would also get rendered when i was using {% include 'nav.html' %}

Comment: It seems strange. The code you pasted has no error. Did you past the same code you are using?

Comment: oh well thats a bummer lol yeah i did. Basically, i have the urls.py set up like normal, calling the function that returns the datetime. Heres the code for it
  def current_datetime(request):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})I dont know how to put code in comments apparently lol if anyone could help me out with that

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got stuck with you inheritance and how things have to work.

`extends` is used for inheritance. But you are trying to include one code snippet into another and that's the work for `include`.

You are not rendering `nav.html`. You are rendering `current_datetime.html` as you mention in the comments, that's why `block` works not as you expected. The code is correct, but your login is a little bit incorrect. Basically I want to point out that nav mustn't extend `current_datetime.html`. It has to be included in it.

Comment: Ah i think i understand what your saying. So how would i go about doing the block method without including nav?

Comment: i was reading my notes, and from what i wrote down, it sounds like you would call the file that extends to the parent file, and then it would load the parent file, is that correct? Seems weird to me, i feel like it would be the other way around

edit: that was the problem. That is really confusing to me lol anyone care to explain why thats normal?